# Error estimation and propagation

Tags: regression, error-propagation

Suppose I pull from literature a relationship between $X$ and $Y$ with reported confidence intervals from a linear regression

$$Y = 2\ (\pm .5) + 5\ (\pm .2)X$$

and then another relationship between $X$ and $Z$

$$X = 11\ (\pm.3) - 1\ (\pm.1)Z.$$

Then, in a different experiment, I'm given $Y$.  I have two questions,

1. How do I calculate my confidence interval for the estimate of $X$?
2. How do I propagate the error in $X$ into my estimate of $Z$?

Many thanks.

Comment: The questions you ask are strange in light of the equations: the first says that $Y$ is to be estimated based on values of $X$ and the second says $X$ is to be estimated based on $Z$. If you are given $Y$, *there is nothing to be estimated* and neither of the equations is appropriate.  Did you perhaps instead want to ask how to estimate $Y$ in terms of $Z$?

Comment: No, I meant the question as asked. A previous set of experiments in multiple papers determined the relationship between X, Y and Z.  Using a different set of experiments, I measure Y and would like to estimate X and Z. My question is how to determine the confidence intervals on the parameters of the inverse of these two linear models.

Comment: You don't (yet) have enough information to answer the inverse question: at a minimum you need estimates of the error variances.  It would help to have the full variance-covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates, too: unless the variables are centered, the slope and intercept will be correlated and this can make a big difference.